# 'localhost' stoped working as an alias for '127.0.0.1' for SSHing into my VirtualBox VM from OSX. Why, and how to fix?

Tags: macos, networking, bash, virtualbox, terminal

The question explains the problem. For months I've never had any problems along these lines. Then, yesterday morning, I couldn't get into my VM! Took a long time to troubleshoot but here was the solution:

```
Brendans-Mac-mini:~ Brendan$ ssh -p 3022 user@localhost
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Brendans-Mac-mini:~ Brendan$ ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1
user@127.0.0.1's password: 
Last login: Tue Jul  1 22:37:59 2014 from 10.0.2.2
```

So, why would this have happened, and more importantly, how do I fix it?

I tried `dig localhost`, which seems to tell me that there's still some kind of connection between localhost and 127.0.0.1:

```
Brendans-Mac-mini:~ Brendan$ dig localhost

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> localhost
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28989
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;localhost.         IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
localhost.      655360  IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.1.1#53(10.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul  2 09:44:44 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43
```

Comment: localhost is normally defined in the /etc/hosts file, not in DNS (although your DNS has an emergency backup entry for it). Check your /etc/hosts file for the line "127.0.0.1       localhost". You can also check whether the system resolver sees it with `dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost`

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yeah, for some reason etc/hosts was empty! That was the problem. Feel free to post as an answer if you'd like, otherwise I'll do it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localhost is normally defined in the /etc/hosts file, not in DNS (although your DNS has an emergency backup entry for it). Here's the normal contents of /etc/hosts in OS X (as of Mavericks):

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

Note that if you need to edit/recreate this file, it must be in plain text format (no formatting at all), with unix-style line endings (linefeeds). You can use a command line editor like `vi` or `nano`; if you want a GUI editor, I tend to recommend [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or its big brother [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) for editing files like this, since they're good about not adding spurious "helpful" things to the files you edit, and also can use admin rights to edit system files (like /etc/hosts).

(Also, it's not really visible or important, but those are tab characters between the addresses and names.)

For testing lookups like this, use `dscacheutil` (`dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost`) instead of something like `dig`. The reason to use `dscacheutil` is that `dig` (and `host` and `nsloogup`) bypasses the system lookup policy and just checks DNS directly, while `dscacheutil` uses the full system lookup policy. As a result, `dig` won't see entries in /etc/hosts, or do mDNS (Bonjour) lookups, or look for Computer entries in directory services, or see cached entries from previous lookups, or...

When you have the hosts file set up properly, here's what `dscacheutil`'s output should look like:

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1
ipv6_address: fe80:1::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: nano was good enough to edit...ended up doing it in `sudo` rather than changing permissions to be able to edit the file. Thanks for this. Looks like I'm missing some other hosts as well!

Comment: `sudo nano` will work fine for things like this. The other entries aren't as critical, but I'd go ahead and add them for completeness' sake.

Comment: [Want to post the same answer over at Ask Different?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/136767/63650) I had posted there originally. I flagged it after you answered and they say it can be answered there too...if not I'll just source this answer and give you credit.

Comment: I copied it on Ask Different, and made a couple of additions. I'll edit in the additions here as well...